# "I just obtained my driving license "or "I have just obtained my driving license"

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

"I just obtained my driving license "or "I have just obtained my driving license"-----Should I use past tense or present perfect in this expression? Or both of them are ok?

Answer (score 2):

Both of your sentences are correct and have the same meaning.

In more typical AmE, one would say

> I just *got* my driver's license.

Comment: How to distinguish past tense and present perfect based on this example?

Comment: @Vince The only thing for using the present perfect is that you're giving news, that means, you are connecting the past event with the present. Like: *I've just obtained my driving licence, I can drive now*.

Comment: In British English, the perfect "have got/obtained" is _much_ more common than the simple past with "just". To my ear, "I just got it" is typically American. But this is clearly an American question, because in British English we have "driving licences" (with a 'c') rather than "driver's licenses" (with an 's').